# Push Notifications in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notifications

I want to make a push notifications, but this code doesn't do what I need. Notifications are also created in place of content.body is always the same text, which is the last element in the foodsForNotifications array. How can I fix this?

```
    func scheduleLocal() {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    for foods in foodForNotifications { // array for content.body
        content.body = foods
    }

    content.title = "AXAXAXAXAXAX"
    content.categoryIdentifier = "alarm"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    for date in datesArr {  // array for date


        var dateComponents = DateComponents()

        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let dateInfo = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
        dateComponents.year = dateInfo.year
        dateComponents.month = dateInfo.month
        dateComponents.day = dateInfo.day
        dateComponents.hour = dateInfo.hour
        dateComponents.minute = dateInfo.minute
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        center.add(request)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to show multiple foods within one notification or several notifications with different foods?

Comment: Several notifications with different foods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for foods in foodForNotifications { // array for content.body
    content.body = foods
}
```

You keep resetting the value, the end value for every notification would be the last item in the list.

You should maybe use a counter or something in this part to get a single unique value from your array for each notification.

```
var index = 0
for date in datesArr {  
     content.body = foodForNotifications[index]
     index = index + 1
}
```

That probably isn't the best way to go about it, it would depend on whats in the arrays and what your goal was but it should give you a good idea of where the problem lies.